# jQuery event trim doesn't work for me

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to trim and shorten some HTML. I use this code:

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
    $.trim('a').substring(0, 10).split(" ").slice(0, - 1).join(" ") + "...";
});​
```

It doesn't work. I tried many things but I can't seem to make it work... Take a look at the example: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ysFNK/1/)

Comment: I just changed the link..(forgot to include Jquery)

Comment: why not use $(function(){...}); instead of that bind?

Comment: @radashk What is the difference, it still doesn't work (:

Comment: .trim() removes the white spaces. What are you trying to do sending 'a' as a parameter... it results in 'a' of course

Comment: Did you actually read the documentation? (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) It contains examples of how to use `$.trim`.

Comment: @Felix Kling Yes I have read it. I made my code simple. In reality it goes along with other coding and a service called 'embedly'. The examples in doc. dont cover that

Comment: But it shows you that `$.trim` expects a string, for example `$.trim('foo ')` returns `'foo'`. If `'a'` is supposed to be a selector, I wonder why you passed it to this function...

Comment: Maybe I made a mistake using 'a' I was trying to make things simple...In reality its a string from embedly http://embed.ly/tour#preview (triggered by urls from feedburner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant [something like](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/LWuLs/):

```
$('a').each(function(i,el) {
   el = $(el);
   old = $.trim(el.html());
   el.html( old.substring(0, 10).split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ") + "..." );
});​
```

alternatively:

```
$('a').html(
     function(){
         return $.trim($(this).html())
                .substring(0, 10)
                .split(" ").slice(0, -1)
                .join(" ") + "...";}
);
```

Comment: Thanks again, appreciate it. I understand this one better

Answer (score 1):

First of all -- jquery trim takes string and not a filter.

[Jquery Trim](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)

here is a working fiddle. you just need to loop over each anchor tag to trim all anchors

http://jsfiddle.net/ysFNK/7/

with loop over anchors :

http://jsfiddle.net/ysFNK/11/